# La uri absoluta: [http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core] no puede resolverse o en web.xml o el los archivos jar desplegados con esta aplicación

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Estoy trabajando con jsp y tomcat quise correr mi programa y me salio todo el siguiente error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: La uri absoluta: [http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core] no puede resolverse o en web.xml o el los archivos jar desplegados con esta aplicación org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54) org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:301) org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:82) org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251) org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:435) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:493) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1450) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144) org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245) org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:207) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:368) org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352) org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

el uri que estiy utilizando es el siguiente : <%@ taglib uri="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> este es el web.xlm :

                           http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core             /WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar                            ControladorIMG         com.sinfloo.controlador.ControladorIMG                  Controlador         com.sinfloo.controlador.Controlador                   ControladorIMG         /ControladorIMG                   Controlador         /Controlador                       30
```

y esto es el pom.xlm:

```
 4.0.0     com.mycompany     proyecto_Ejem1     1.0-SNAPSHOT     war

<name>proyecto_Ejem1</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>9.2.1.jre11</version> 
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Utilizo netbeans y jsp tengo el error siguiente :
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: La uri absoluta: [http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core] no puede resolverse o en web.xml o el los archivos jar desplegados con esta aplicación
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:301)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:82)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:435)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:493)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:207)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)